# SQL: Join/union of two tables, on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Provided the following structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE "CHANGES" (    
  "ID" NUMBER(38),
  "LAST_UPD_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);

CREATE TABLE "EXPORT_LOG" (
  "ID" NUMBER(38),
  "LAST_EXPORT" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);
```

Table `CHANGES` contains:

```
----------------------------
| ID  |  LAST_UPD_DATE     |
----------------------------
| 123 | 12-MAY-16 12.23.23 |
| 124 | 12-MAY-16 12.24.23 |
| 125 | 12-MAY-16 12.11.23 |
----------------------------
```

and `EXPORT_LOG`

```
----------------------------
| ID  |  LAST_EXPORT       |
----------------------------
| 124 | 12-MAY-16 12.23.12 |
| 125 | 12-MAY-16 12.12.24 |
----------------------------
```

I need to get the records in `CHANGES` that either don't exist in `EXPORT_LOG` or, if exists, get records with `LAST_UPD_DATE` later than `LAST_EXPORT`. 
So in the above example, I should be getting 123 and 124.

I'm trying different JOINs but I cannot seem to get the result I want: 
`INNER JOIN` is used for intersections, `LEFT JOIN` gets ALL of first table, but only those of second table that match a condition you set - none of these is what I want. So is the solution some sort of UNION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM CHANGES AS t1
LEFT JOIN EXPORT_LOG AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE (t2.ID IS NULL) OR (t1.LAST_UPD_DATE > t2.LAST_EXPORT)
```

This will return all records of `CHANGES` table that don't have a match in `EXPORT_LOG` table **plus** the records of `CHANGES` table that have a `LAST_UPD_DATE` that is later than `LAST_EXPORT`.

Comment: Thank you, that does the job. However, can you explain how this is so? Isn't the `where` clause applied AFTER the result of `ON t1.ID = t2.ID`? Because without the `WHERE` there are no records with `t2.ID` being `null`

Comment: @mavili - yes, there are. That is exactly what an outer join (in this case, left join) does - it creates the records you are talking about, where t1.id does not have a corresponding t2.id. (Note that this doesn't mean "with t2.id being null" - not sure what you meant by that.)

Answer (score 0):

One method is to translate the conditions directly using `exists`:

```
select c.*
from changes c
where not exists (select 1 from export_log el where c.id = el.id) or
      not exists (select 1 from export_log el where c.id = el.id and el.last_export > c.last_upd_date);
```

This can be simplified to:

```
select c.*
from changes c
where not exists (select 1 from export_log el where c.id = el.id and el.last_export > c.last_upd_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below mentioned code and provide me the feedback. It should work as per your requirement.

```html
SELECT CH.ID, CH.LAST_UPD_DATE
FROM CHANGES CH, EXPORT_LOG EL 
WHERE CH.ID = EL.ID(+) 
AND ((EL.ID IS NULL) OR (CH.LAST_UPD_DATE > EL.LAST_EXPORT));
```

Comment: Giorgios already posted this solution, with one difference: he used the recommended syntax for joins. There is no reason in this query to use the obsolete, Oracle-proprietary syntax for outer joins. The demerit is for both reasons but especially for the first.